# Deallocating function's A run-time memory inside function B

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stl, heap-memory

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

void addSomeContent(queue<TCHAR*> &s)
{
    static int counter=0;
    TCHAR* buffer = new TCHAR[250]; //Allocate memory on heap

    wsprintf(buffer,TEXT("foo%d"),counter);

    s.push(buffer);
    counter++;

    if(counter < 10)
    addSomeContent(s);

}


int main (void)
{
    queue<TCHAR*> strings; 

    addSomeContent(strings);

    while(!strings.empty()) 
    {   
        wcout<<strings.front()<<endl;
        strings.pop();
    }

    //Here I want to destroy the "buffer" from the function "addSomeContent"
    wcout<<TEXT("Memory has been cleaned!\n");

    system("pause");
    return (0);
}
```

If I had deleted the wide char array at the end of the function, I couldn't have processed my queue which references to it. Now, my simple program compiles and works fine, but obviously keeping a garbage in heap isn't considered as a safe programming practice. 
 
How to delete the "buffer" just after using it last time?

Comment: `queue<unique_ptr<TCHAR>>` or just `delete[] strings.back()` before `strings.pop()`. Also you should be using `back` not `front`

Comment: @SethCarnegie Make an answer from your comment.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Why back if I want to implement a FIFO data structure?

Comment: FWIW, there's nothing *unsafe* about letting the OS take care of heap deallocation, **so long as** it's part of your life-cycle design.  (This is assuming you're on such an OS.)  Indeed, it can often times be *more damaging* to attempt, after-the-fact, to add explicit deallocates just for the sake of *best practice*.

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74 you're right, I forgot you were using `queue`, it would be `front` then. I put it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `queue<unique_ptr<TCHAR[]>>` to avoid memory deallocation entirely, or you can simply deallocate the memory before you remove it from the `queue` like so:

```
delete[] strings.front();
strings.pop();
```

Comment: unique_ptr<TCHAR> is not correct, look at my answer. You want unique_ptr to delete[], not to delete. This is most definitely a memory leak.

Comment: @cooky451 thank you very very much, I fixed it. Also it wouldn't be a memory leak, it would be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Seth about using unique_ptr for your queue, or you can simply call

```
   delete[] strings.front()
```

before the `strings.pop()`

`front()` should be used to ensure we clean the element we are about to `pop()` i.e. the oldest element in the queue rather than `back()`, which is the newest!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to work with strings, I would consider to just use

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;
std::queue<tstring> strings;
```

Otherwise you could use

```
std::queue<std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]>> strings; // notice the [], they are important!
```

unique_ptr is C++11, but I think it's supported by all major compilers. I would not even consider to delete[] this manually. It is very vulnerable to errors, and not exception safe.